# Avoid command events blocking a kill focus event in wxPython

Tags: focus, wxpython

I'm writing a class to generate a frame on left click of a taskbar icon. The desired behaviour is for this frame to disappear on loss of focus, so I have bound a `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS` event to the panel in my `LeftClickFrame()` object.

This works fine if I only have a `wx.StaticText` widget in the frame, but if I add a `wx.HyperlinkCtrl` the `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS` event no longer fires. I get the same blocking behaviour with `wx.RadioButton` widgets, but not with `wx.StaticBitmap`.

I believe this is something to do with the fact that `wx.HyperlinkCtrl` and `wx.RadioButton` widgets are both controls and emit command events, but I'm not clear on what I have to do to rearrange my class so the `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS` event is still processed when one or both of these controls are present.

I have the following code:

```
class LeftClickFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, frame):
        super(LeftClickFrame, self).__init__(frame,
                                             style=wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR|
                                                   wx.CAPTION)
        self.tbicon = frame.taskbar_icon
        self.tbicon.options_window = self
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY) 
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.Close)

        self.main_vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        statuses_hbox = self.GetStatusesVBox()
        self.main_vbox.Add(statuses_hbox)
        self.main_vbox.Add((-1, 10))        
        links_vbox = self.GetLinksVBox()
        self.main_vbox.Add(links_vbox, flag=wx.TOP|wx.CENTER, border=20)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.main_vbox)

    def GetStatusesVBox(self, statuses):
        statuses_vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        for status in statuses:
            battery_statuses_txt = wx.StaticText(self.panel,
                                                 wx.ID_ANY, status)
            statuses_vbox.Add(battery_statuses_txt,
                              flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT, border=10)
        return statuses_vbox

    def GetLinksVBox(self):
        links_vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        link1 = wx.HyperlinkCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Adjust screen brightness')
        link1.Bind(wx.EVT_HYPERLINK, self.tbicon.LaunchPowerOptions)
        links_vbox.Add(link1, flag=wx.CENTER|wx.TOP, border=5)
        return links_vbox

    def Close(self):
        self.tbicon.options_window.Destroy()
        self.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try EVT_ACTIVATE instead of EVT_KILL_FOCUS since it does not work in your case.
And you can use event.GetActive() to check if this frame is in focus.

```
def InitUI(self):
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_ACTIVATE, self.Close)  #bind it to Frame



def Close(self, evt):
    if evt.GetActive() != True:
        #do window close
```